# Delete Certain Range of Content on Excel Using Script Task on SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, script-task, vba

I'm Trying to Delete some range(A2:BC2000) of Content on Excel using Script task on SSIS, or do you guys gave any alternate methods.
Here is the code that i used

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim Wexcel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim Wb As Workbook = Wexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Depart.xlsx")
        Dim wf As WorksheetFunction = Wexcel.WorksheetFunction
        Dim sheet As Worksheet

        For Each sheet In Wexcel.Worksheets
            If wf.CountA(sheet.Range("A2:BC20000").Value) > 0 Then
                Wexcel.DisplayAlerts = False
                sheet.Delete()
                Wexcel.DisplayAlerts = True


            End If
        Next sheet
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

if i run my package with this scripttask i'm getting an error below

[image]

Can anyone has solution to this??

Comment: Just a suggestion - is it possible your script tries to delete all sheets? - that would cause an error since there must be at least one left.

Comment: your right !! it was my fault i was just deleting all the sheets. thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm Trying to Delete some range(A2:BC2000) of Content*

In your code, you have these lines:

```
 Wexcel.DisplayAlerts = False
sheet.Delete()
Wexcel.DisplayAlerts = True
```

These 3 lines delete the sheet, not the range.

If you just want to clear contents of the specified range, then use:

```
sheet.Range("A2:BC2000").ClearContents
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Absolutely right !!!! awesome , It Worked!!!!!! Thank you for the help!!